# How to AspxGridView FilterRow Search C# method?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, devexpress

i have use  AspxGridView which has FilterRow property. FilterRow property is working good in LinqServerMode,LinqDataSource etc. it means that:

if i type filter control, filterRow propert works fine

BUT  i don't coding above! i have done that like below:

```
public class MyClass
{
      void GetData()
{

 // dosomething
}
}


void FillGrid()
{

    MyAspxGridView.DataSource = new MyClass().GetData();
   MyAspxGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Your FilterRow's Autofilling property is not working! i think that this method ALL TIME open connection. How to get data thping filter with My FillGrid Method....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this problem, you should call the FillGrid method within the Page_Init method.  For more details, please refer to the [Why might paging (sorting, grouping, filtering) not work in the ASPxGridView?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/K18183.aspx) article.